# Oracle specific selection

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table as follows

```
OWNERID 
PET_QUANTITY 
PET_TYPE
```

PET_TYPE is either DOG, CAT, or BIRD

There is one record per owner/pet so if have a dog and bird there would be two records and pet_quantity would be 2 in both records.

I want all the owner_IDs where the person has two pets and the pets are a dog and a cat.

Comment: I hope this a dumb school question (or similar) because otherwise  the data model really sucks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, the data model is rather unfortunate since the value for `PET_QUANTITY` for a particular row depends on data in other rows.  That violates basic normalization rules.  And that, in turn, creates a situation where you will inevitably get out of sync and so you have to determine whether the `PET_QUANTITY` rules or whether the number of rows in the table rules.  You'd be much better served by a properly normalized data model.

Assuming that `PET_QUANTITY` rules when there is a discrepancy, one option would be to use an `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT owner_id
  FROM your_table
 WHERE pet_quantity = 2
   AND pet_type = 'CAT'
INTERSECT
SELECT owner_id
  FROM your_table
 WHERE pet_quantity = 2
   AND pet_type = 'DOG'
```

Another would be to do something like

```
SELECT owner_id, COUNT(DISTINCT pet_type)
  FROM your_table
 WHERE pet_quantity = 2
   AND pet_type IN ('DOG', 'CAT')
 GROUP BY owner_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pet_type) = 2
```